# Definition of internal energy for quantum systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, energy, quantum-information, lamb-shift

In the last days I questioned my self on the definition of internal energy in quantum systems. Let consider a bipartite system with hamiltonian $H^{AB} = H^A + H^B + V^{AB}$ for instance. Then, if the bipartite is not interacting, i.e. $V^{AB}=0$, then the definition is quite obvious, i.e. I'd say

$$
\mathcal{U}^A(t) = \langle H^A\rangle
$$

However, if the systems interact, then how to generalise this expression? Is the internal energy still the one defined in that way? Or it should be renormalised with the energetic contribution from the coupling, i.e.

$$
\mathcal{U}^A(t) = \langle H^A\rangle + \langle \mathcal{H}^A(t)\rangle
$$
where $\mathcal{H}^A(t)=\text{Tr}_B\left\{V^{AB}\rho_B(t)\right\}$.

I'm saying this because it is known that interacting qubit have energy levels shifted and then more energy is exctractable due to the coupling. What I'm questioning is if this energy should be considered internal or external. It seems to me that the concept of internal energy should not be connected with "extractable" energy (this is ergotropy).

For this reason, my intuition says no, since it is some energy that is brought by a sort of "coupling" and there must be an external operator that turns on the coupling and introduce this energy, i.e. is not really internal.

My problem is that people speak about shifted levels as something that happens locally and hence it would make sense to think of it as an internal energy.

What do you think is the best and more physically grounded option for the internal energy?